# Selecting rows in sqlite based on date

Tags: sqlite, date

I have a table of which one column holds dates in this format '04/17/2014'.
I want to select rows of the table based on time. I'm trying to get all rows after a certain date. After reading posts here I tried the following, which doesn't seem to work. I get a lot of rows from 2013 back with this query. Can anybody help?

```
select Value_Date from Table_Outstanding
where VALUE_DATE > '04/12/2014'
```

Comment: What about if you use the same format in your argument in your SQL statement as it's stored as in the database? If it's stored like YYYY-MM-DD then why not use that very format in your WHERE-clause?

Comment: It actually is stored in that format

Comment: Ah, okay.. I understood from your post that it was stored like YYYY-MM-DD, but in your WHERE-clause it was rather DD-MM-YYYY.

Comment: Oh, very sorry. I made a mistake. it's actually stored in '04/12/2014' this format. My bad

Comment: That's alright, what about doing something like... WHERE Value_Date > date('your-date')

Comment: Doesn't return anything.
select Value_Date from Table_Outstanding
where VALUE_DATE > date('04/12/2014')

Comment: Think I found the problem. The data type of "VALUE_DATE" is TEXT. I don't think I have an option here. Is there anyway I can still compare dates?

Answer (score 0):

This did it. Thanks everybody.

```
select * from Table_Outstanding
where strftime('%m/%d/%Y', VALUE_DATE) > '04/12/2014'
```

Comment: If it works and is the correct answer, you should accept it. Even if it's your own.

Comment: It says I can accept the answer in 2 days. I'll try then.

Comment: This is a string comparison. Do you really want to match a record with the date `05/01/2001`?